# Geodesics on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, curves, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Suppose that one has a compact hyperbolic surface realised as a quotient $X=\Gamma\setminus\mathbb{H}$. So in particular, $\Gamma$ consists only of hyperbolic elements of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and the identity. Suppose that one takes an element $\gamma\in\Gamma$ non-identity, and for the sake of simplicity suppose is it primitive (so not a non-trivial power of another element in the group).

The axis of this element $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{H}$ will project to a closed geodesic on the surface $X$ through the natural covering map. Suppose now that I consider some other point $z\in\mathbb{H}$ that is not on the axis of $\gamma$ and I consider the projection of the geodesic segment between $z$ and $\gamma(z)$ onto the surface. This will give me a closed curve and will be a geodesic also since we projected a geodesic segment. It won't necessarily however be a closed geodesic since it may not close smoothly at the image of $z$ on the surface.

Question: Will this geodesic loop be freely homotopic to the closed geodesic originating from the projection of the axis? (Of course, in the case where $\gamma$ were non-primitive I would expect that it would be freely homotopic to some power of this projected axis instead).

I believe this to be true but I am not sure how one would go about showing it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true and pretty easy to prove.

Let $\delta(s)$ be the shortest geodesic arc from $z$ to $A = \text{Axis}(\gamma)$, parameterized by $s \in [0,d(z,A)]$ with initial endpoint $\delta(0)=z$, with terminal endpoint $\delta(d(z,a)) = P \in A$, and hitting $A$ at a right angles at the point $P$.

Note that $\gamma \circ \delta(s)$ is, similarly the shortest geodesic arc from $\gamma(z)$ to $A$, hitting $A$ at right angles at the point $\gamma(P)$.

Now take a parameterized family of geodesic arcs $\zeta_t$ from $\delta(t)$ to $\gamma\circ\delta(t)$, defined for $t \in [0,d(z,A)]$. If you parameterize this family by normalized arc length (normalized to have domain $[0,1]$), and if you also normalize the parameter $t$ to vary over $[0,1]$, and then project to the quotient, that will give you the desired free homotopy.

Notice: this proof does not use that $\gamma$ is primitive. The key fact is that for a primitive element $\gamma$, the axis of $\gamma$ is identical to the axis of $\gamma^k$ for all $k \ge 1$, the only distinction being the length of a fundamental domain along the axis.

Comment: Great thank you. I am slightly confused however with why this projects to a free homotopy on the surface. For instance, what if I consider another geodesic segment in the plane with endpoints identified on the surface to give a closed loop (but generated by a different group element so the axis is different). Then, can't I just draw two geodesics from the endpoints of the segment to the axis touching it perpendicularly and obtain a family $\zeta_t$ in a similar way? Why would this not be a free homotopy on the surface? I don't see where taking $\gamma\circ\delta$ plays a role for this?

Comment: This construction works with $\gamma$ replaced by any hyperbolic element of the deck transformation group, with any $z \in \mathbb H^2$, with $\delta$ the shortest geodesic arc from $z$ to $A=\text{Axis}(\gamma)$, and with $\zeta_t$ replaced by the shortest geodesic arc from $\delta(t)$ to $\gamma(\delta(t))$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Does that address your comment?

Comment: My comment is more if say I have $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in the group, I consider the geodesic segment between some z and $\gamma_1 z$ and then I take $\delta_1$ to be the shortest geodesic from z to A=Axis($\gamma_2$) and $\delta_2$ to be the shortest geodesic from $\gamma_1 z$ to $A$ and construct a family of arcs whose endpoints are on $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$. Why doesn't this pass to a free homotopy between the geodesic loop at z generated by $\gamma_1$ and the closed geodesic generated by the axis of $\gamma_2$ in the same way the $\zeta_t$ do in your proof?

Comment: In your latest comments, it's true that $\zeta_0(0)$ and $\zeta_0(1)$ are in the same orbit, namely $\gamma_1(\zeta_0(0))=\zeta_0(1)$. And it is also true that $\zeta_1(0)$ and $\zeta_1(1)$ are in the same orbit, namely $\gamma_2(\zeta_1(0))=\gamma_2(\zeta_1(1))$. But for $0 < t < 1$ there is no guarantee that $\zeta_t(0)$ and $\zeta_t(1)$ are in the same orbit, so the path $\zeta_t$ need not project to a closed path (in fact there will exist $t$ such that it **does not** project to a closed path), hence the projection does not define a free homotopy.

Comment: In my answer, when the path $\delta$ is projected down to $X$, that projected path is the path along which the base point of the loops travels in the free homotopy. But in your latest comment, the projections of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ to $X$ are **distinct** paths in $X$, and the homotopy in $X$ is therefore not a **free** homotopy.

Comment: Perfect thank you, this makes sense. Is there an obvious way to see that there will necessarily exist a t such that the $\zeta_t$ won't project down to a closed path? Is it because otherwise I could join the free homotopies to get a free homotopy on the surface between the closed geodesics generated by the two different axes?

Comment: Well, $\zeta_t$ projects to a closed path for all $t$ if and only if for all $t$ there exists a deck transformation $\gamma_t$ such that $\gamma_t(\zeta_t(0))=\zeta_t(1)$. Using that the action is free and properly discontinuous, together with continuity of $\zeta$, the deck transformation $\gamma_t$ is independent of $t$.